# Does every $\bar\partial$ harmonic form being $\partial$ closed make a manifold Kähler?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I'm reading Tian's paper 《[Smoothness of the universal deformation space of compact Calabi-Yau manifolds and its Peterson-Weil metric](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812798411_0029)》, in page 635, there is a statement that:

> For a compact Kähler manifold $X$, let $\mathcal H^1(X,\Omega^{n-1})=\{\phi \in \Gamma(X,\Omega^{(n-1,1)})\mathrel|\bar{\partial}\phi=0,\bar{\partial}^*\phi=0\}$, $\forall\phi\in\mathcal H^1(X,\Omega^{n-1}),\partial \phi=0$. See [GH].

If my understanding is right, it is a result of Kähler identity: $\Delta_\bar\partial=\Delta_\partial$, and my question is: Can we relax the Kähler condition a bit and get the same conclusion? As we know, for a compact Kähler manifold, every $\bar\partial$ harmonic form is $\partial$ closed, but contrarily, if a compact manifold satisfying every $\bar\partial$ harmonic form is $\partial$ closed, is this manifold automatically Kähler? Or does some more general manifolds like Moishezon manifolds or $\partial\bar\partial$-manifolds suffice? Has anybody thought about this question before?

Comment: Are you aware of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.0331.pdf (section 3, especially the proof of Thm 1.2) and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.05107.pdf (Thm 3.3)?

Comment: @YangMills , yes, I have read the first one which bypassed my question and answered my  original  concerned question after I post this question, but this question post here still remained unanswered, the second one I have just read but find it also not related to my question posted here.